# Can't post through endpoint in jest

Tags: node.js, routes, jestjs

I am working on the little exercise and writing tests for it. All my tests using `GET` with endpoint ('/api/blogs') are working but when it comes to `POST` data it gives a weird object:

```
{
      '$__': {
        strictMode: true,
        getters: {},
        _id: '60c5d31b1fd4814db33f879e',
        wasPopulated: false,
        activePaths: { paths: [Object], states: [Object], stateNames: [Array] },
        pathsToScopes: {},
        cachedRequired: {},
        session: null,
        '$setCalled': {},
        emitter: { _events: {}, _eventsCount: 0, _maxListeners: 0 },
        '$options': { defaults: true }
      },
      isNew: true,
      '$locals': {},
      '$op': null,
      _doc: {
        _id: '60c5d31b1fd4814db33f879e',
        title: 'Suomi',
        author: 'Ler',
        url: 'ola.com',
        likes: 9
      }
    }
```

[This](https://github.com/rd9911/UniHelsinkiFullStack/tree/main/part4) is the whole project in github.

This is the test that I want to pass:
`blog.test.js`

```
describe('post', () => {
    test('post a blog', async () => {
        const blogs = await testHelper.blogsInDB();
        const blog = new Blog({
            title: 'Suomi',
            author: 'Ler',
            url: 'ola.com',
            likes: 9
        });
        await api.post('/api/blogs')
            .send(blog)
            .expect(201)
            .expect('Content-Type', /application\/json/);
        expect(await testHelper.blogsInDB()).toHaveLength(blogs.length + 1);
    });
```

This is the router that is receiving requests
`blogs.js`

```
blogRouter.post('/', async (req, res) => {
    const body = req.body;
    console.log(body);
    if (body.title === undefined && body.url === undefined) {
        res.status(400).send({error: 'Missing data'});
        return;
    }
    const blog = new Blog({
        title: body.title,
        author: body.author,
        url: body.url,
        likes: body.likes ? body.likes : 0
    });
  
    const result = await blog.save();
    res.status(201).json(result);
});
```

Note: when I remove the `if` logic test is passing.
Also, everything works fine with Postman.
When in my test, if I am saving a new object with `obj.save()` it works. But I need to also make sure that I can post through endpoint. So I need to get access to the object with `req.body.title`.

1. So why I am getting two different responses from Postman and my tests?
2. How can I post through the endpoint ('/api/blogs')?

Any help will be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you need to use `new Blog` in your test, it will create an instance of Mongoose document (the weird object in your log). Create a Mongoose document is the job of the API. You only need to send the Javascript object.

```
describe('post', () => {
    test('post a blog', async () => {
        const blogs = await testHelper.blogsInDB();
        const blog = { // just send the javascript object
            title: 'Suomi',
            author: 'Ler',
            url: 'ola.com',
            likes: 9
        };
        await api.post('/api/blogs')
            .send(blog)
            .expect(201)
            .expect('Content-Type', /application\/json/);
        expect(await testHelper.blogsInDB()).toHaveLength(blogs.length + 1);
    });
```